# prefect) Can't connect to Server API at http://0.0.0.0:4200/api in docker container

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, prefect

I tried to build docker container to use prefect server. But there is a problem that I can't connect the server in container from local environment.

my prefect version : 2.10.4(latest)

As I search this issue, there is no exact solution for this issue.
Pleas let me know if you need more information to solve this issue. Thanks.

My Steps --

1. docker-compose.yml (ref: https://medium.com/the-prefect-blog/how-to-self-host-prefect-orion-with-postgres-using-docker-compose-631c41ab8a9f)

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  ### PostgreSQL Database
  database:
    image: postgres:14.1-alpine
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=prefect
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=prefect
      - POSTGRES_DB=prefect
    expose:
      - 5432
    volumes: 
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    profiles: ["server"]

  ### Prefect Orion API
  orion:
    image: prefecthq/prefect:2-python3.11
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - prefect:/.prefect
    entrypoint: ["prefect", "server", "start"]
    environment:
      - PREFECT_SERVER_API_HOST=0.0.0.0
      - PREFECT_API_DATABASE_CONNECTION_URL=postgresql+asyncpg://prefect:prefect@database:5432/prefect
    ports:
      - 4200:4200
    depends_on:
      - database
    profiles: ["server"]
      
volumes:
  prefect:
  postgres:
```

2. Enter **"http://localhost:4200/api"**
3. Result (figure)
   [image]

---

Here's my tries.
I changed PREFECT_SERVER_API_HOST to 127.0.0.1, public IP, 0.0.0.0 but not works.
I changed PREFECT_SERVER_API_HOST not to 4200 but not works
I entered the 127.0.0.1:4200, localhost:4200, 0.0.0.0:4200
just build dockerfile (not docker compose)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like `PREFECT_SERVER_API_HOST` is used to set IP address to listen at server side (inside container). But outside of container you have to request different IP address.

So if you set `PREFECT_SERVER_API_HOST=localhost` then it will be correct for connections outside container (because `http://localhost:4200/api` UI is working correct). But! in this case server will listen `localhost` inside of container and it will be not accessible outside.

So you have to set `0.0.0.0` for listening interface and `localhost` as URL for requests sent via UI. And here is [`PREFECT_UI_API_URL`](https://docs.prefect.io/latest/api-ref/prefect/settings/#prefect.settings.PREFECT_UI_API_URL) parameter created especially for this case:

```yaml
...
    environment:
      - PREFECT_SERVER_API_HOST=0.0.0.0
      - PREFECT_UI_API_URL=http://localhost:4200/api
...
```

Comment: Thanks. I try to change my code. But another problem happen... In one word, "table worker_pool already exists". I ask this issue here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76045807/prefect-sqlite3-operationalerror-table-worker-pool-already-exists-error-when-i) Please let me know if you know the solution. Thank you again.