# prefect) sqlite3.OperationalError: table worker_pool already exists Error when I build docker container using prefecthq/prefect image

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, prefect

I tried to build container to use prefect server.
So I use docker compose and "prefecthq/prefect" image. (version : prefecthq/prefect:2.10-python3.9)

But, This error occur. (main error sentence)

> sqlite3.OperationalError: table worker_pool already exists

I don't understand that I'm not generate table "worker_pool" in docker environment. Is Something wrong in my docker-compose.yml?

Here's my codes

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  orion:
    image: prefecthq/prefect:2.10-python3.9
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - prefect:/root/.prefect
    entrypoint: ["prefect", "server", "start"]
    environment:
      - PREFECT_SERVER_API_HOST=0.0.0.0
      - PREFECT_UI_API_URL=http://localhost:4200/api
    ports:
      - 4200:4200
```

And Here's entire logs

```
Attaching to test_bed-orion-1
test_bed-orion-1  |
test_bed-orion-1  |  ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ _____
test_bed-orion-1  | | _ \ _ \ __| __| __/ __|_   _|
test_bed-orion-1  | |  _/   / _|| _|| _| (__  | |
test_bed-orion-1  | |_| |_|_\___|_| |___\___| |_|
test_bed-orion-1  |
test_bed-orion-1  | Configure Prefect to communicate with the server with:
test_bed-orion-1  |
test_bed-orion-1  |     prefect config set PREFECT_API_URL=http://0.0.0.0:4200/api
test_bed-orion-1  |
test_bed-orion-1  | View the API reference documentation at http://0.0.0.0:4200/docs
test_bed-orion-1  |
test_bed-orion-1  | Check out the dashboard at http://0.0.0.0:4200
test_bed-orion-1  |
test_bed-orion-1  |
test_bed-orion-1  |
test_bed-orion-1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1900, in _execute_context
test_bed-orion-1  |     self.dialect.do_execute(
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 736, in do_execute
test_bed-orion-1  |     cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/sqlite/aiosqlite.py", line 108, in execute
test_bed-orion-1  |     self._adapt_connection._handle_exception(error)
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/sqlite/aiosqlite.py", line 236, in _handle_exception
test_bed-orion-1  |     raise error
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/sqlite/aiosqlite.py", line 90, in execute
test_bed-orion-1  |     self.await_(_cursor.execute(operation, parameters))
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_concurrency_py3k.py", line 68, in await_only
test_bed-orion-1  |     return current.driver.switch(awaitable)
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_concurrency_py3k.py", line 121, in greenlet_spawn
test_bed-orion-1  |     value = await result
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiosqlite/cursor.py", line 37, in execute
test_bed-orion-1  |     await self._execute(self._cursor.execute, sql, parameters)
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiosqlite/cursor.py", line 31, in _execute
test_bed-orion-1  |     return await self._conn._execute(fn, *args, **kwargs)
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiosqlite/core.py", line 137, in _execute
test_bed-orion-1  |     return await future
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiosqlite/core.py", line 110, in run
test_bed-orion-1  |     result = function()
test_bed-orion-1  | sqlite3.OperationalError: table worker_pool already exists
test_bed-orion-1  |
test_bed-orion-1  | The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
test_bed-orion-1  |
test_bed-orion-1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/prefect/server/api/server.py", line 481, in lifespan
test_bed-orion-1  |     await run_migrations()
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/prefect/server/api/server.py", line 404, in run_migrations
test_bed-orion-1  |     await db.create_db()
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/prefect/server/database/interface.py", line 55, in create_db
test_bed-orion-1  |     await self.run_migrations_upgrade()
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/prefect/server/database/interface.py", line 63, in run_migrations_upgrade
test_bed-orion-1  |     await run_sync_in_worker_thread(alembic_upgrade)
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/prefect/utilities/asyncutils.py", line 91, in run_sync_in_worker_thread
test_bed-orion-1  |     return await anyio.to_thread.run_sync(
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/anyio/to_thread.py", line 31, in run_sync
test_bed-orion-1  |     return await get_asynclib().run_sync_in_worker_thread(
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 937, in run_sync_in_worker_thread
test_bed-orion-1  |     return await future
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 867, in run
test_bed-orion-1  |     result = context.run(func, *args)
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/prefect/server/database/alembic_commands.py", line 24, in wrapper
test_bed-orion-1  |     return fn(*args, **kwargs)
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/prefect/server/database/alembic_commands.py", line 53, in alembic_upgrade
test_bed-orion-1  |     alembic.command.upgrade(alembic_config(), revision, sql=dry_run)
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/alembic/command.py", line 378, in upgrade
test_bed-orion-1  |     script.run_env()
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/alembic/script/base.py", line 576, in run_env
test_bed-orion-1  |     util.load_python_file(self.dir, "env.py")
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/alembic/util/pyfiles.py", line 94, in load_python_file
test_bed-orion-1  |     module = load_module_py(module_id, path)
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/alembic/util/pyfiles.py", line 110, in load_module_py
test_bed-orion-1  |     spec.loader.exec_module(module)  # type: ignore
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/prefect/server/database/migrations/env.py", line 147, in <module>
test_bed-orion-1  |     apply_migrations()
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/prefect/utilities/asyncutils.py", line 248, in coroutine_wrapper
test_bed-orion-1  |     return run_async_from_worker_thread(async_fn, *args, **kwargs)
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/prefect/utilities/asyncutils.py", line 177, in run_async_from_worker_thread
test_bed-orion-1  |     return anyio.from_thread.run(call)
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/anyio/from_thread.py", line 49, in run
test_bed-orion-1  |     return asynclib.run_async_from_thread(func, *args)
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 970, in run_async_from_thread
test_bed-orion-1  |     return f.result()
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 446, in result
test_bed-orion-1  |     return self.__get_result()
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 391, in __get_result
test_bed-orion-1  |     raise self._exception
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/prefect/server/database/migrations/env.py", line 141, in apply_migrations
test_bed-orion-1  |     await connection.run_sync(do_run_migrations)
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/asyncio/engine.py", line 548, in run_sync
test_bed-orion-1  |     return await greenlet_spawn(fn, conn, *arg, **kw)
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_concurrency_py3k.py", line 128, in greenlet_spawn
test_bed-orion-1  |     result = context.switch(value)
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/prefect/server/database/migrations/env.py", line 129, in do_run_migrations
test_bed-orion-1  |     context.run_migrations()
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "<string>", line 8, in run_migrations
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/alembic/runtime/environment.py", line 868, in run_migrations
test_bed-orion-1  |     self.get_context().run_migrations(**kw)
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/alembic/runtime/migration.py", line 622, in run_migrations
test_bed-orion-1  |     step.migration_fn(**kw)
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/prefect/server/database/migrations/versions/sqlite/2022_11_24_143302_fe77ad0dda06_add_worker_tables.py", line 25, in upgrade
test_bed-orion-1  |     op.create_table(
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "<string>", line 8, in create_table
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "<string>", line 3, in create_table
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/alembic/operations/ops.py", line 1255, in create_table
test_bed-orion-1  |     return operations.invoke(op)
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/alembic/operations/base.py", line 401, in invoke
test_bed-orion-1  |     return fn(self, operation)
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/alembic/operations/toimpl.py", line 114, in create_table
test_bed-orion-1  |     operations.impl.create_table(table)
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/alembic/ddl/impl.py", line 354, in create_table
test_bed-orion-1  |     self._exec(schema.CreateTable(table))
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/alembic/ddl/impl.py", line 193, in _exec
test_bed-orion-1  |     return conn.execute(  # type: ignore[call-overload]
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/future/engine.py", line 280, in execute
test_bed-orion-1  |     return self._execute_20(
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1705, in _execute_20
test_bed-orion-1  |     return meth(self, args_10style, kwargs_10style, execution_options)
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/ddl.py", line 80, in _execute_on_connection
test_bed-orion-1  |     return connection._execute_ddl(
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1472, in _execute_ddl
test_bed-orion-1  |     ret = self._execute_context(
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1943, in _execute_context
test_bed-orion-1  |     self._handle_dbapi_exception(
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2124, in _handle_dbapi_exception
test_bed-orion-1  |     util.raise_(
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 211, in raise_
test_bed-orion-1  |     raise exception
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1900, in _execute_context
test_bed-orion-1  |     self.dialect.do_execute(
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 736, in do_execute
test_bed-orion-1  |     cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/sqlite/aiosqlite.py", line 108, in execute
test_bed-orion-1  |     self._adapt_connection._handle_exception(error)
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/sqlite/aiosqlite.py", line 236, in _handle_exception
test_bed-orion-1  |     raise error
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/sqlite/aiosqlite.py", line 90, in execute
test_bed-orion-1  |     self.await_(_cursor.execute(operation, parameters))
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_concurrency_py3k.py", line 68, in await_only
test_bed-orion-1  |     return current.driver.switch(awaitable)
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_concurrency_py3k.py", line 121, in greenlet_spawn
test_bed-orion-1  |     value = await result
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiosqlite/cursor.py", line 37, in execute
test_bed-orion-1  |     await self._execute(self._cursor.execute, sql, parameters)
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiosqlite/cursor.py", line 31, in _execute
test_bed-orion-1  |     return await self._conn._execute(fn, *args, **kwargs)
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiosqlite/core.py", line 137, in _execute
test_bed-orion-1  |     return await future
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiosqlite/core.py", line 110, in run
test_bed-orion-1  |     result = function()
test_bed-orion-1  | sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) table worker_pool already exists
test_bed-orion-1  | [SQL:
test_bed-orion-1  | CREATE TABLE worker_pool (
test_bed-orion-1  |     id CHAR(36) DEFAULT (
test_bed-orion-1  |     (
test_bed-orion-1  |         lower(hex(randomblob(4)))
test_bed-orion-1  |         || '-'
test_bed-orion-1  |         || lower(hex(randomblob(2)))
test_bed-orion-1  |         || '-4'
test_bed-orion-1  |         || substr(lower(hex(randomblob(2))),2)
test_bed-orion-1  |         || '-'
test_bed-orion-1  |         || substr('89ab',abs(random()) % 4 + 1, 1)
test_bed-orion-1  |         || substr(lower(hex(randomblob(2))),2)
test_bed-orion-1  |         || '-'
test_bed-orion-1  |         || lower(hex(randomblob(6)))
test_bed-orion-1  |     )
test_bed-orion-1  |     ) NOT NULL,
test_bed-orion-1  |     created DATETIME DEFAULT (strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%f000', 'now')) NOT NULL,
test_bed-orion-1  |     updated DATETIME DEFAULT (strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%f000', 'now')) NOT NULL,
test_bed-orion-1  |     name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
test_bed-orion-1  |     description VARCHAR,
test_bed-orion-1  |     type VARCHAR,
test_bed-orion-1  |     base_job_template JSON DEFAULT '{}' NOT NULL,
test_bed-orion-1  |     is_paused BOOLEAN DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
test_bed-orion-1  |     concurrency_limit INTEGER,
test_bed-orion-1  |     default_queue_id CHAR(36),
test_bed-orion-1  |     CONSTRAINT pk_worker_pool PRIMARY KEY (id),
test_bed-orion-1  |     CONSTRAINT uq_worker_pool__name UNIQUE (name)
test_bed-orion-1  | )
test_bed-orion-1  |
test_bed-orion-1  | ]
test_bed-orion-1  | (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
test_bed-orion-1  |
test_bed-orion-1  | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
test_bed-orion-1  |
test_bed-orion-1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/datastructures.py", line 702, in __getattr__
test_bed-orion-1  |     return self._state[key]
test_bed-orion-1  | KeyError: 'services'
test_bed-orion-1  |
test_bed-orion-1  | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
test_bed-orion-1  |
test_bed-orion-1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 677, in lifespan
test_bed-orion-1  |     async with self.lifespan_context(app) as maybe_state:
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 181, in __aenter__
test_bed-orion-1  |     return await self.gen.__anext__()
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/prefect/server/api/server.py", line 486, in lifespan
test_bed-orion-1  |     await stop_services()
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/prefect/server/api/server.py", line 468, in stop_services
test_bed-orion-1  |     if app.state.services:
test_bed-orion-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/datastructures.py", line 705, in __getattr__
test_bed-orion-1  |     raise AttributeError(message.format(self.__class__.__name__, key))
test_bed-orion-1  | AttributeError: 'State' object has no attribute 'services'
test_bed-orion-1  |
test_bed-orion-1  | Application startup failed. Exiting.
test_bed-orion-1  | Server stopped!
```

Please let me know how to remove work_pool or solve this problem..!
Thanks to read my question and if you need more information, ask me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefect is creating sql database at first run inside mounted `prefect` volume.

At second run database is already created and don't need to be created again. To solve problem you may use two ways:

1. Remove `prefect` folder contents every time before starting container and that will allow prefect to recreate db every time
2. Set [PREFECT_API_DATABASE_MIGRATE_ON_START](https://docs.prefect.io/latest/api-ref/prefect/settings/#prefect.settings.PREFECT_API_DATABASE_ECHO) parameter to `False`. That will stop prefect to create new db on start and allow to re-use current db if it exists